# What happens to the CronWorkflows in Cadence if a cluster is down when a workflow should have started?

Tags: cadence-workflow, uber-cadence

What is the behaviour of CronWorkflows in the event that the Cadence cluster is down while a workflow should have started? When the cluster comes back, would we expect the workflow to still be started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all workflows that didn't start yet are going to start right away. If multiple starts were missed only one will be executed.